# Xcode 8: Storyboard UILabel attributed line spacing is NOT honored

Tags: xcode, uilabel

I'm setting the a UILabel's attributed line spacing in the storyboard as such:

[image]

But in the simulator it's not working at all:

[image]

What am I doing wrong with this?